# how to pass -pg to gcc in cygwin

Tags: gcc, cygwin, gprof

I just want to test -pg, the source file is very simple, my environment is 
cygwin,

```
$ uname -a 
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 SHA-LPLATOW 2.8.2(0.313/5/3) 2017-07-12 10:58 x86_64 Cygwin

$ vi pgtest.c

#include <stdio.h>
void main(void){
    printf("hello, world\n");        
}
```

no -pg compiling is OK.

```
$ gcc -c pgtest.c
$ gcc -o pgtest.exe pgtest.o
```

but -pg report error

```
$ gcc -pg -c pgtest.c
$ gcc -o pgtest.exe pgtest.o
pgtest.o:pgtest.c:(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `__fentry__'
pgtest.o:pgtest.c:(.text+0x1): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__fentry__'
pgtest.o:pgtest.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `_monstartup'
pgtest.o:pgtest.c:(.text+0xe): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_monstartup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried LDFLAGS, it is the same.

```
export LDFLAGS="-pg" ; gcc -o pgtest.exe pgtest.o
```

Comment: What about simply `gcc -o pgtest.exe pgtest.o -pg`?

Comment: @chtz it is ok, but I want to pass it by environment variables, because I use scons.

Comment: @netawater, I think you will have to check your `scons` documentation, or places where you can gets `scons` help. (Here with a `scons` tag, maybe?)

I know next to nothing about `scons`. 

Can you add the `'-pg'` flag to your `scons` set up?  Does `scons` look at environment variables? `gcc` does not look at `LDFLAGS` or anything like that. You can set `LDFLAGS` before calling `make` because `make` will look at it and pass that on to `gcc`.

Comment: @SeeJayBee thanks, I found use LINKFLAGS instead of LDFLAGS is OK for scons

Answer (score 4):

from the gcc info page

> '-pg'
>        Generate extra code to write profile information suitable for the
>        analysis program 'gprof'.  You must use this option when compiling
>        the source files you want data about, and you must also use it when
>        linking.

so if you want to do a separate compilation and linking you need to repeate the `-pg`

```
$ gcc -c pgtest.c -pg
$ gcc -o pgtest.exe pgtest.o -pg
```

Comment: thanks, but I use link command in scons, I can set set it directly, can be finished by environment variables